# Undefined variables in form with google Recaptcha?

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

I am trying to get a form with google's Recaptcha to work. Below is the code that I have so far. What am I doing wrong?? When filling in the form and clicking the SEND button i get the notices below. It seems it has to do with this section of my PHP code:

```
          $to = 'eddyhilhorst@fotel.eu';
        $subject = 'A new contact form has been submitted';
        $htmlContent = "
            <h1>Contact request details</h1>
            <p>'.$first_name.' From:</b>".$gender." ".$first_name." ".$last_name."</p>
            <p><b>Company name: </b>".$company_name."</p>
            <p><b>Customer number: </b>".$customer_number."</p>
            <p><b>Email address: </b>".$email_address."</p>
            <p><b>Telephone number: </b>".$telephone_number."</p>
            <p><b>Message subject: </b>".$message_subject."</p>
            <p><b>Message: </b>".$message_content."</p>
        ";
        // Always set content-type when sending HTML email
        $headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0" . "\r\n";
        $headers .= "Content-type:text/html;charset=UTF-8" . "\r\n";
        // More headers
        $headers .= 'From:'.$gender.' '.$first_name.' '.$last_name.' <'.$email.'>' . "\r\n";
        //send email
        @mail($to,$subject,$htmlContent,$headers);
```

Notice: Undefined variable: gender in /home/sites/www.hildesign.nl/web/fotelcontactform/form.php on line 26

Notice: Undefined variable: first_name in /home/sites/www.hildesign.nl/web/fotelcontactform/form.php on line 26

Notice: Undefined variable: last_name in /home/sites/www.hildesign.nl/web/fotelcontactform/form.php on line 26

Notice: Undefined variable: company_name in /home/sites/www.hildesign.nl/web/fotelcontactform/form.php on line 27

Notice: Undefined variable: customer_number in /home/sites/www.hildesign.nl/web/fotelcontactform/form.php on line 28

Notice: Undefined variable: email_address in /home/sites/www.hildesign.nl/web/fotelcontactform/form.php on line 29

Notice: Undefined variable: telephone_number in /home/sites/www.hildesign.nl/web/fotelcontactform/form.php on line 30

Notice: Undefined variable: message_subject in /home/sites/www.hildesign.nl/web/fotelcontactform/form.php on line 31

Notice: Undefined variable: message_content in /home/sites/www.hildesign.nl/web/fotelcontactform/form.php on line 32

Notice: Undefined variable: gender in /home/sites/www.hildesign.nl/web/fotelcontactform/form.php on line 38

Notice: Undefined variable: first_name in /home/sites/www.hildesign.nl/web/fotelcontactform/form.php on line 38

Notice: Undefined variable: last_name in /home/sites/www.hildesign.nl/web/fotelcontactform/form.php on line 38

```js
autosize(document.querySelectorAll('#message_content'));



var validator = $("#comment_form").validate({
  ignore: [],
  rules: {
    gender: {
      required: true,
    },
    first_name: {
      required: true,
      minlength: 2
    },
    last_name: {
      required: true,
      minlength: 2
    },
    email: {
      required: true,
      email: true,
      minlength: 4
    },
    email_again: {
      equalTo: '[name="entry[email]"]'
    },
    message_subject: {
      required: true,
      minlength: 2
    },
    message: {
      required: true,
      minlength: 4
    },
    hiddenRecaptcha: {
      required: function() {
        if (grecaptcha.getResponse() == '') {
          return true;
        } else {
          return false;
        }
      }
    }
  }
});
```

```css
html {
  text-align: center
}

body {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0px auto;
  text-align: left;
}

@font-face {
  font-family: Questrial;
  src: url(Questrial-Regular.otf);
}

div {
  font-family: Questrial;
}

input {
  font-family: Questrial;
}

text-area {
  font-family: Questrial;
}

span {
  font-family: Questrial;
}

p {
  font-family: Questrial;
}

form {
  font-family: Questrial;
}

#comment_form {
  width: 302px;
}

.label-radio {
  font-size: 0.8em;
  color: #d8e3e6;
  margin-right: 10px;
  font-family: questrial;
}

.inputfield3 {
  height: 33px;
  max-height: 33px;
  width: 302px;
  border-radius: 16px;
  margin-top: -10px;
  margin-bottom: 17px;
  padding: 0px 10px 0px 10px;
  overflow: hidden;
  border: none;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  display: inline-block !important;
  font-family: questrial;
  font-size: 0.8em;
}

.inputfield2 {
  height: 33px;
  max-height: 33px;
  width: 302px;
  border-radius: 16px;
  margin-top: -10px;
  margin-bottom: 0px;
  padding: 0px 10px 0px 10px;
  overflow: hidden;
  border: none;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  display: inline-block !important;
  font-family: questrial;
  font-size: 0.8em;
}

.textareafield {
  max-height: 350px;
  width: 302px;
  max-width: 302px;
  border-radius: 16px;
  margin-top: -10px;
  margin-bottom: 17px;
  padding: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
  overflow: hidden;
  border: none;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  display: inline-block !important;
  font-family: questrial;
  font-size: 0.8em;
}

#g-recaptcha-outer {
  width: 302px;
  height: 72px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  overflow: hidden;
  border-radius: 16px;
  margin: -10px auto 20 auto;
}

#recaptcha-header {
  margin: 30px 0px -15px 0px;
  color: #d8e3e6;
  font-size: 1.0em;
  font-family: questrial;
  font-size: 0.8em;
  letter-spacing: -0.03em;
}

#contact_submit_button {
  display: block;
  text-decoration: none;
  margin: 10px auto 80px auto;
  width: 230px;
  height: 33px;
  padding: 0px 15px 0px 15px;
  background-color: rgb(0, 157, 233);
  color: #ffffff;
  border-radius: 16px;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  font-family: questrial;
  font-size: 1em;
}

.requiredmark {
  margin: 0px 0px 0px 295px;
  display: inline-block;
  color: #d8e3e6;
  padding: 20px 0px 0px 0px;
}

.requiredmark2 {
  margin: -39px 0px 0px 295px;
  display: inline-block;
  color: #d8e3e6;
  padding: 20px 0px 0px 0px;
}

.requiredmark-radio {
  margin: 20px 0px 0px 0px;
  display: inline-block;
  color: #d8e3e6;
  font-family: questrial;
}

.error {
  display: none;
}

.error_show {
  color: red;
}

input.invalid,
textarea.invalid {
  border: 1px solid red;
}

input.valid,
textarea.valid {}

label.error {
  margin-top: -10px;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
  float: none;
  color: red;
  vertical-align: top;
  display: block;
  font-family: Questrial;
}

​ #hiddenRecaptcha-error {
  margin-top: 65px!important;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
  float: none;
  color: red;
  vertical-align: top;
  display: block;
  font-family: Questrial;
}

​ .gender {
  border-radius: 16px;
  margin-top: 5px;
  margin-bottom: 7px;
  padding: 0px 10px 0px 10px;
  overflow: hidden;
  border: none;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  display: inline-block !important;
  font-family: questrial;
  font-size: 0.8em;
}

#gender-error {
  float: right;
  margin-bottom: 0px!important;
  margin-top: 20px!important
}
```

```html
<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit']) && !empty($_POST['submit'])):
    if(isset($_POST['g-recaptcha-response']) && !empty($_POST['g-recaptcha-response'])):
        //your site secret key
        $secret = 'MySecretKey_is_here';
        //get verify response data
        $verifyResponse = file_get_contents('https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify?secret='.$secret.'&response='.$_POST['g-recaptcha-response']);
        $responseData = json_decode($verifyResponse);
        if($responseData->success):
            //contact form submission code
            $name = !empty($_POST['gender'])?$_POST['gender']:'';
            $email = !empty($_POST['first_name'])?$_POST['first_name']:'';
            $message = !empty($_POST['last_name'])?$_POST['last_name']:'';
   $name = !empty($_POST['company_name'])?$_POST['company_name']:'';
            $email = !empty($_POST['customer_number'])?$_POST['customer_number']:'';
            $message = !empty($_POST['email'])?$_POST['email']:'';
   $message = !empty($_POST['email_again'])?$_POST['email_again']:'';
   $name = !empty($_POST['telephone_number'])?$_POST['telephone_number']:'';
            $email = !empty($_POST['message_subject'])?$_POST['message_subject']:'';
            $message = !empty($_POST['message_content'])?$_POST['message_content']:'';
            
            $to = 'eddyhilhorst@fotel.eu';
            $subject = 'A new contact form has been submitted';
            $htmlContent = "
                <h1>Contact request details</h1>
                <p>'.$first_name.' From:</b>".$gender." ".$first_name." ".$last_name."</p>
                <p><b>Company name: </b>".$company_name."</p>
                <p><b>Customer number: </b>".$customer_number."</p>
    <p><b>Email address: </b>".$email_address."</p>
                <p><b>Telephone number: </b>".$telephone_number."</p>
                <p><b>Message subject: </b>".$message_subject."</p>
    <p><b>Message: </b>".$message_content."</p>
            ";
            // Always set content-type when sending HTML email
            $headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0" . "\r\n";
            $headers .= "Content-type:text/html;charset=UTF-8" . "\r\n";
            // More headers
            $headers .= 'From:'.$gender.' '.$first_name.' '.$last_name.' <'.$email.'>' . "\r\n";
            //send email
            @mail($to,$subject,$htmlContent,$headers);
            
            $succMsg = 'Your contact request have submitted successfully.';
        else:
            $errMsg = 'Robot verification failed, please try again.';
        endif;
    else:
        $errMsg = 'Please click on the reCAPTCHA box.';
    endif;
else:
    $errMsg = '';
    $succMsg = '';
endif;
?>

<head>
  <script src='https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js'></script>
  <script src="https://assets.webshopapp.com/photographycoursetour/autosize.js?2" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.15.0/jquery.validate.js"></script>
  <script src="{{ 'iframeresizer-min.js' | url_asset }}" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script src="https://assets.webshopapp.com/photographycoursetour/iframeresizer-contentwindow-min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>

<body>

  <form id="comment_form" action="form.php" method="post">

    <div class="compulsoryfield">
      <input class="gender" type="radio" name="gender" value="Mr" required><label class="label-radio">Mr.</label>
      <input class="gender" type="radio" name="gender" value="Ms" required><label class="label-radio">Ms.</label>
      <span class="requiredmark-radio">*</span>
    </div>

    <div class="compulsoryfield"><span class="requiredmark">*</span>
      <input id="first_name" name="first_name" class="inputfield3" type="text" placeholder="first name" required>
    </div>

    <div class="compulsoryfield"><span class="requiredmark2">*</span>
      <input id="last_name" name="last_name" class="inputfield3" type="text" placeholder="last name" required>
    </div>

    <input class="inputfield3" type="text" name="company_name" placeholder="company name (if applicable)">
    <input class="inputfield3" type="text" name="customer_number" placeholder="customer number (on invoice if available)">
    <br>

    <div class="compulsoryfield"><span class="requiredmark">*</span>
      <input id="email" name="email" class="inputfield3" type="email" placeholder="email address" required>
    </div>

    <div class="compulsoryfield"><span class="requiredmark2">*</span>
      <input id="email_again" name="emai_again" class="inputfield3" type="email" placeholder="re-enter email address to confirm" required></div>


    <input class="inputfield3" type="text" name="telephone_number" placeholder="telephone number (country code included)">
    <br>
    <div class="compulsoryfield"><span class="requiredmark">*</span>
      <input id="message_subject" name="message_subject" class="inputfield3" type="text" placeholder="subject of message" required>
    </div>

    <div class="compulsoryfield"><span class="requiredmark2">*</span>
      <textarea id="message_content" name="message_content" class="textareafield" type="text" placeholder="add your message here" rows="8" cols="39" required></textarea></div>


    <p id="recaptcha-header">before sending, please show us you're real:</p>

    <div><span class="requiredmark">*</span>
      <div id="g-recaptcha-outer" class="compulsoryfield2">
        <div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="6LdBLBUUAAAAAI6eMRYRaA5B-EN_UDKGzwHtNMU1" required></div>

      </div>
      <input type="hidden" class="hiddenRecaptcha required" name="hiddenRecaptcha" id="hiddenRecaptcha">
      <br><br>
      <input id="contact_submit_button" type="submit" name="submit" value="SEND" onclick="myFunction()">

  </form>

  <div class="errMsg">PLease click on the Recaptcha box.</div>
```

Comment: The error messages quite clearly say that you have not defined the variables before using them. For example `$gender=$_POST['gender'];`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you're trying to use values from variables that don't exist.

It looks like you're assigning your `POST`ed values to the incorrect variables.  Look at this section of code -

```
//contact form submission code
  $name = !empty($_POST['gender'])?$_POST['gender']:'';
  $email = !empty($_POST['first_name'])?$_POST['first_name']:'';
  $message = !empty($_POST['last_name'])?$_POST['last_name']:'';
  $name = !empty($_POST['company_name'])?$_POST['company_name']:'';
  $email = !empty($_POST['customer_number'])?$_POST['customer_number']:'';
  $message = !empty($_POST['email'])?$_POST['email']:'';
  $message = !empty($_POST['email_again'])?$_POST['email_again']:'';
  $name = !empty($_POST['telephone_number'])?$_POST['telephone_number']:'';
  $email = !empty($_POST['message_subject'])?$_POST['message_subject']:'';
  $message = !empty($_POST['message_content'])?$_POST['message_content']:'';

  $to = 'eddyhilhorst@fotel.eu';
  $subject = 'A new contact form has been submitted';
  $htmlContent = "
    <h1>Contact request details</h1>
    <p>'.$first_name.' From:</b>".$gender." ".$first_name." ".$last_name."</p>
    <p><b>Company name: </b>".$company_name."</p>
    <p><b>Customer number: </b>".$customer_number."</p>
    <p><b>Email address: </b>".$email_address."</p>
    <p><b>Telephone number: </b>".$telephone_number."</p>
    <p><b>Message subject: </b>".$message_subject."</p>
    <p><b>Message: </b>".$message_content."</p>
  ";
```

You are assigning values for "gender" to the variable `$name` and the value for "first_name" to `$email`.  If you update your variable names to match the `POST`ed fields your code should work.